# Veracode scan: How to get the total expected "Effort to Fix" for all the issues found in a scan?

Tags: veracode

I am analysing the Veracode scan reports for some applications. I have the PDF reports. These do not have the total "Effort to Fix" for all the issues found.

Can someone guide me to get it?